# How to bring in the right margin of a paragraph with border

Tags: html, css

(This is question about CSS/HTML.)

If I have a single-line paragraph that doesn't extend to the right margin and I've turned it into a text box by putting border around it, how can I keep that border from being extended all the way to the right margin?

```
<p style="border: 1px solid black;">
This is a test.
</p>
```

looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| This is a test.                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

when I want it to look like this (without me having to guess at hard-coding *margin-right*):

```
+-----------------+
| This is a test. |
+-----------------+
```

I'm speaking here, of course, from a left-to-right orientation (so, not Hebrew or Arabic).

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I assume that you could have several paragraphs in a row, one after the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use `display: inline-block;` on that element. + apply your border.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this (warning: will not work on IE7):

```
<p id='yourPara'>
    This is a test.
</p>
```

CSS

```
#yourPara {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you don't want to change the `display` value of the `p`, then either use a different element that defaults to `inline` or wrap the text in the `p` with an inline element (like `span`, for example) and put the border on that.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynJXt/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<p>
<span style="border: 1px solid black;">This is a test.</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is float the paragraphs and then clear them:

```
p.neatBox {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

See for example: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8GbkJ/

The advantage here is that you don't have to worry about `inline-block`'s following each other in succession and perhaps appearing two or more per line.

The only thing to watch out for is that margins don't collapse on floated elements, so you would need to set either the top margin or the bottom margin to control the inter-paragraph spacing.